# I have accidentally removed FCM registration tokens from my server

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have accidentally removed FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) registration tokens from my server, is there any way that I can get all the tokens (like via Firebase console) ?

I don't have a backup, unfortunately.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Very unlikely. If you don't have any backups at all then your only option is to release an update for your app which registers all your users again for FCM.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Thank you.

Comment: @XaverKapeller sounds like an answer :-)